# Haskell type expression

Tags: haskell-platform, template-haskell, haskell

I have two questions about Haskell type expression:

**Question 1 -**

I would like to declare a type NODE

```
data NODE = Node String ATTR
```

and a type ATTR contains 3 sub-type as follow:

> Source Bool
>
> Target Bool
>
> Ghost  Int

```
data ATTR = Source Bool | Target Bool | Ghost Bool
```

But the above declaration does not satisfy the requirement that ATTR can contain whatever the combination of sub-types such as:

- ATTR can contain Source Bool and Target Bool at once
- ATTR can contain Source Bool, Target Bool and Ghost Int at once
- ATTR can even be empty (contain nothing)

**Question 2 -**

I would like to declare a type GRAPH, in which a graph can contain 1 or many Statements (STMTS) or contain no Statement if the graph is empty. So I declare as follow:

```
data GRAPH = Graph String STMTS
data STMTS = STMT | STMTS
```

But again, as you see the recursive data type STMTS will repeat infinitively.

Comment: This sounds like homework, so here are some hints. Q1: consider the use of "Maybe".  Q2: You need to consider this alternative definition of a list: data NonEmptyList a = Single a | Many a (NonEmptyList a). Don't worry about infinite data structures; Haskell eats them for breakfast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question 1 I would say to use something like

```
data Attr = Attr (Maybe Bool) -- Source 
                 (Maybe Bool) -- Target 
                 (Maybe Bool) -- Ghost
```

For Question 2, I would use something like

```
data Graph = Graph [STMT]
```